# How to create string HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(@"languagetext","PersonalReportFrench") in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have hardcoded value in javascript in my aspx page which is working

```
PersonalReportLink.innerHTML = '<%=(String)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(@"languagetext","PersonalReportFrench")%>';
```

now I want do it dynamically what I am trying is

> sel_lang ="French" //i am geting from the user  PerReportStr = '<%=
>   (String)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(@"languagetext","PersonalReport'+
>   sel_lang + '") %>';

which giving me empty string after execution ie PerReportStr="" 
I think correct keyword is not get passed to resource file

Reason is I am not able to form below string correctly using C#

**(String)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(@"languagetext","PersonalReportFrench")**

Please help me to create above string using C# ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this Javascript is directly on the ASPX page then you should be able to access the global resource object using this syntax:

```
PersonalReportLink.innerHTML = '<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("languagetext","PersonalReportFrench") %>';
```

However, you can get issues when trying to localise strings nested in javascript files. If this does not work then you may need to localise the Javascript in a slightly more complex way.

You can use Javascript files as resources using the ScriptManager's EnableScriptLocalization attribute.

Add the following to any page which requires the resource:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scriptResources.js" ResourceUICultures="fr-FR,de-DE" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The important things to note here are the path to the script file, the list of cultures in `ResourceUICultures="fr-FR,de-DE"` and `EnableScriptGlobalization="true"`.

Next, add a JS file to your project called scriptResources.js and populate it with the resources for your default language:

```
var PersonalReportFrench = 'My English text';
var resourceTwo = 'More English text';
```

Then add another JS file for the localised strings, `scriptResources.fr-FR.js`:

```
var PersonalReportFrench = 'Mon texte Français';
var resourceTwo = 'Texte plus Français';
```

Now, providing that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is set to the correct culture and it matches the locale in the scripts file name and `ResourceUICultures` attribute, the ScriptManager will load the correct JS file and you can use the variables in your JS like so:

```
PersonalReportLink.innerHTML = PersonalReportFrench;
```

Comment: I will check and get back to you.